# Does the output shape of tf.nn.conv2d gives any information about total number of images?

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

```
`input = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([10,5,5,5]))
 filter = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3,3,5,7]))
 op = tf.nn.conv2d(input, filter, strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')`
```

In above code output size will be (10x3x3x7).Does it means that there will be total 70 images of size(3x3) because filter has 7 channels so 10x7 is the total number of images?

Comment: Yes. you already provided the answer. `op` size it self provides your answer. (10x3x3x7)--> (batch size/number of images x height x width x channels)

Answer (score 2):

Batch Size : 10 and Input Image Channels : 5

Output Channels of Conv2D : 7

Each image in a batch has 7 activations (output channels of the layer).

And Yes, there will be 10x7 : 70 3x3 Activation Maps at the end of this layer.

Are you looking for more information ??

## Update:

Input depth dimension of filter should be same as number of input channels.

Input and Strides are never going to be the same. Stride [1,2,2,1] implies : conv filter moves horizontally with 2 pixel stride and vertically 2 pixel stride. First 1 is for batch and last 1 is for channel : means it should process all images in the batch and all channels.

To understand better, look at the animation for convolution demo given in here:
http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/#conv

## Update 2

Each 3x3 filter among 7 filters is applied through all input channels to get one value for each output channel. (shown in the figure)

k : input channel index
j : output channel index
You can see, each output channel " h*j* " is combination sum of all input channels multiplied with specific filter " w*j* "

[image]

Used from https://sites.google.com/site/lsvrtutorialcvpr14/home/deeplearning

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Can you please explain stride[1,2,2,1]. When we select filter its depth dimension should be same as input image depth/input image channel. I read that the parameters of input and stride shout be same. then why stride is not like[10,2,2,5]?

Comment: Input channel is basically the depth of the input-image. Filter is also applied along depth dimension. If there are 10 input image and 2 input channel. Does it mean that first time when we move filter, we cover first channel of first image then move it on the second channel of the first image and then we ho the second image's first channel. If this is the case means we are contradicting the statement that filter is applied along depth dimension. Can you please explain it briefly?

Comment: R.K, sorry, I might have confused you - adding more explanation. Did you understand it now ?

Comment: Now i'm quite clear from the animation of convolution. Thank you  so much

Comment: please accept/vote the answer so that question is closed. Thanks.